# Upload file to library with custom properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, template, sharepoint-library, forms-library

I have simple library with custom columns (language, country etc.) and when user will upload file I want to force him to fill information about file which he will upload.

I can't set it up because when I will use "Upload" button I can see only two fields (attachment and Version Comments). I know that users can edit file properties later but I need to have it in the same step where I attach file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just after you press "OK" you will be presented with **another** screen asking for your custom properties.

If you make one or more of these fields mandatory, the user cannot checkin the document and make it visible to others, without providing data for these custom fields. (Which I asume is what you want to ensure)